# Migrated Windows 10 Roaming Profiles to new server, now seeing Error - Event ID 1521

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, roaming-profile

Elaboration:

I migrated the storage of some people's roaming profile from one Windows Server to another, and updated the profile location through Active Directory to reflect the change. Now for everyone I've done this to I'm seeing the notification on these users:

`There was a problem with your roaming profile you have been logged on with your previously saved local profile. Please see the event log for details or contact your administrators.`

After looking through the local machine's Event Viewer, I'm seeing Event ID 1521 with the description:

`Windows cannot locate the server copy of your roaming profile and is attempting to log you on with your local profile. Changes to the profile will not be copied to the server when you log off. This error may be caused by network problems or insufficient security rights.`

`DETAIL - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

I configured the share and permissions to match [what is listed here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/folder-redirection/deploy-roaming-user-profiles#required-permissions-for-the-file-share-hosting-roaming-user-profiles), and I can confirm access by navigating to \\servername\profileshare$\userprofile.V6, and being able to access the contents of the user profile (and only that user profile) perfectly fine.

The server in question doesn't have anything special installed (ie an Antivirus), so I'm wondering if someone could help me figure out what 'other process' Event Viewer is talking about, and to solve the problem.

Update: This error doesn't appear to be consistent - sometimes I can sign in without problems, but more often than not I get the message described above.